# Ruby on Rails - AWS-SDK configuration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm using AWS-SDK gem in my Rails project, and I want a kind-of initializer file to connect directly to my repo and make changes directly in the Rails console, something like this:

```
    # At config/initializers/aws.rb

    Aws::S3::Client.new(
      :access_key_id => 'ACCESS_KEY_ID',
      :secret_access_key => 'SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
    )
```

I've looked for documentation or tutorials but it's not clear for me. How do I do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I've found the solution:

1. Create the file `aws.rb` in your `/config/initializers` folder.
2. In `aws.rb` write:

   ```
   S3Client = Aws::S3::Client.new(
       access_key_id: 'ACCESS_KEY_ID',
       secret_access_key: 'SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
       region: 'REGION'
   )
   ```

That's it. Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: You are creating a global constant in your example. While this works, I would recommend limiting your config initializers to only configuring credentials.

Answer (score 8):

i think you can try like this

put this in aws.rb

```
AWS.config(
   :access_key_id => ENV['ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
   :secret_access_key => ENV['SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
)
```

and when you initialize the object wherever you need, will call the configuration

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new
```

Comment: That configuration corresponds to the version 1.0, the current version has a different way to do it...

Comment: As for version 2, if you get the credentials from ENV, you don't have to setup the config. The AWS clients you will use ENV by default.

Answer (score 8):

To share configuration between AWS service client in a Rails application, configure the AWS SDK for Ruby from a config initializer.

```
# config/initializers/aws-sdk.rb
Aws.config.update(
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new('access-key-id', 'secret-access-key'),
  region: 'us-east-1',
)
```

Now you can construct a client object from any service without any options:

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new
ec2 = Aws::EC2::Client.new
```

Please note, you should avoid hard-coding credentials into your application. This can be a security risk if your source code is accessed and it makes it difficult to rotate credentials.

I recommend using hands-off configuration via `ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']` and `ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']`, or an EC2 instance profile.

Comment: could u help me discover why i am having this error with aws-sdk-rails https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50914089/aws-sdk-rails-uninitialized-constant-awss3-nameerror

Answer (score 2):

Also with aws-sdk-rails (1.0.0)

```
# config/initializers/aws.rb
Aws.config[:credentials] = Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS CONFIGURATION:-

**in config/intitalizers/s3.rb**

```
Paperclip.interpolates(:s3_eu_url) { |attachment, style|
  "#{attachment.s3_protocol}://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/#{attachment.bucket_name}/#{attachment.path(style).gsub(%r{^/}, "")}"
}
```

**config/initializers/paperclip.rb**

```
require 'paperclip/media_type_spoof_detector'         
module Paperclip         
 class MediaTypeSpoofDetector        
    def spoofed?         
      false       
    end       
  end        
end 

Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:id/:style/:filename'
S3_CREDENTIALS = Rails.root.join("config/s3.yml")
```

**/config/s3.yml**

```
development:
  bucket: development_bucket
  access_key_id: AKIA-----API KEYS---------MCLXQ
  secret_access_key: qTNF1-------API KEYS--------DTy+rPubaaG
production:
  bucket: production_bucket
  access_key_id: AKI-----API KEYS--------LXQ
  secret_access_key: qTNF1dW---API KEYS---+rPubaaG
```

hope you have `gem "aws-sdk"`in the `Gemfile`

**add you asset in model**

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
 :styles => {:view => "187x260#"},
:storage => :s3,
:s3_permissions => :private,
:s3_credentials => S3_CREDENTIALS
```

**verify using rails console with static image in public**

```
Image.create(avatar: File.new("#{Rails.root}/public/images/colorful_blue.jpg"))
```